# StringStream/c_str() corruption in C++

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, c-strings

I'm having some issues with std::cout, std::stringstream, and std::string.c_str(). Mainly, it seems that there's stuff that's getting caught in a buffer somewhere, and I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

If you don't like reading code in StackOverflow, here are the relevant links to my github:
The [TLString class](https://github.com/tomthorogood/TurnLeftLib/tree/0517/utils/src/tlstring), the [Test class](https://github.com/tomthorogood/TurnLeftLib/blob/0517/utils/src/test.h), and [the unit test](https://github.com/tomthorogood/TurnLeftLib/blob/0517/tests/tlstring_test.cpp) -- and you can skip to the end where I state my more concise question.

In my unit test, I have the following code:

```
    Test <std::string> strtest; // A unit test object expecting strings.
    Test <const char*> chtest; // A unit test object expecting const char*s
    // ...

    TurnLeft::Utils::TLString str3("Exterminate.");
    // ...

    /* Basically, name() and expect() will use the passed arg. 
     * in the output in order to
     * display output such as the following:
     * str(): expecting 'Exterminate.' | Actual 'Exterminate.' => PASS
     */
    strtest.name("str()").expect("Exterminate.").test( str3.str() );

    /* To try and determine where the corruption was occuring, I did a 
     * simple cout here, and got what should be the expected result of 
     * the next test,
     * meaning that the actual test should be succeeding.
     */
    std::cout << str3.c_str() << std::endl //outputs Exterminate. normally.

    /* But when I try to invoke that same method (c_str()) within the test
     * object, it simply copies the argument passed in for name().
     */
    chtest.name("c_str()").expect("Exterminate.").test( str3.c_str() );
    // Should output 'Exterminate.' as in the saatement before, but instead
    // outputs 'c_str()'.
```

Here's the code for the Test class:

```
namespace unittest{
static std::string status[2] = {"FAIL", "PASS"};

    template <class ExpectedResult>
    class Test
    {
     private:
        ExpectedResult  expected;
        ExpectedResult  actual;
        std::string     testName;
     public:
        Test();
        Test <ExpectedResult>& expect (ExpectedResult value);
        Test <ExpectedResult>& name   (std::string);
        void test   (ExpectedResult value);
    };

template <class ExpectedResult> Test <ExpectedResult>&
Test<ExpectedResult>::expect(ExpectedResult value)
{    
    expected = value;
    return *this;
}

template <class ExpectedResult>
Test <ExpectedResult>&
Test<ExpectedResult>::name(std::string aName)
{
    testName = aName;
    return *this;
}

    template <class ExpectedResult>
    void Test<ExpectedResult>::test(ExpectedResult value)
    {
        actual = value;
        std::cout << testName << ": ";
        std::cout << "Expecting: " << expected << " | ";
        std::cout << "Actual: " << actual;
        std::cout << " => " << status[actual==expected] << std::endl;
    }
```

The TLString class is one that I'm writing that will give some more fluid operation to strings in C++ (for example, concatenation). It uses a stringstream in order to handle these operations. The `TLStream::c_str()` method is really just doing this: `return stream.str().c_str();`

So, I'm really confused about how `actual` is being assigned the value of `testName`. I'm not sure where the conflict is occurring, given that the only time those to variables come close to interacting is when they are both output to to the CLI, and even moreso as in this case, those two are different datatypes.

I've written in the c_str() functionality because, quite simply, you just never know when some third-party library is going to rely on C strings instead of C++ strings, and saw no reason to limit my class. Even within std::ios, you need to use c strings for some things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering, what's wrong with using `append` or `operator+/operator+=` for concatenation?

Comment: I implement operator+ and operator+= in the class I'm writing; I didn't think it prudent to overload an operator with a standard library object. There's also some other functionality I'm adding. I didn't know about append, however. So, that's super useful.

Comment: Bah, I thought that branch had all the fixes. I also noticed while trying to solve this prolbme that I was returning a copy of the object, instead of a reference to the same object. The actual definition reads Test<ExpectedResult>& name(std::string); I must have not added & committed after making those changes. My apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::stringstream.str()` returns a temporary object of type `std::string`. This temporary goes out of scope when `TLStream::c_str()` returns, leaving the returned `char const*` pointer pointing to freed memory.

Comment: oh hooohhhhhh. Fascinating. I guess I'll just nix that method altogether then. On the rare occasion I'll need to get a c string, I'll just call it on the return string object from the str() method instead of trying to pull double duty.

Answer (score 0):

```
    std::cout << " => " << status[actual==expected] << std::endl;
```

This `==` compares a `const char*` pointing to the string literal `"Exterminate"` with a `const char*` pointing to `str3.c_str()`

Those pointers are different.

You need to compare them using something like `strcmp`, not by pointer equality.

Comment: Also valid, but per the above answer, I'm removing that method entirely, as it's more elegant to just return a c++ string, and invoke the c_str() method on that when necessary.